# Smarty and configuration

Tags: configuration, smarty

I have some questions about the smarty optimisation.

1) I'm new using smarty and I wonder, If I want to make a web site, what are the configurations I need ? I heard talk of :

```
$smarty->setTemplaceDir(..);
$smarty->caching=1;
```

Anything else ?

2) I often see :

```
$smarty->display("index.tpl", $var);
```

What do the second paramètre ?
It's the same thing do to :

```
$smarty->assign($var);
$smarty->display("index.html");
```

It seems the second param $var is for a best cache optimization, isn't it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this is documented at http://www.smarty.net/ . To setup your needs, I recommend you to read about the following methods:

- `setCaching`
- `setCacheLifetime`
- `setTemplateDir`
- `setCacheDir`
- `setCompileDir`
- `addPluginsDir`

Also interesting could be `loadFilter('output','trimwhitespace')` and `escape_html`. The second parameter of display, is the cache_id. Its helpful when you want to store multiple caches for one template or template stack. For example if you display a user profile page and the cache_id is set to a user unique identifier (a user id or something), then smarty will create a cache file for every user for the same template. This could be also solved with `nocache` sections / modifiers. In *my* conclusion its better to work with a cache_id when the script execution takes a long time without caching. You can set a default cache_id too. Just `$smartyobject->cache_id = *somevalue*`. This is helpful when you work in combination with `isCached`, cause this method also accept a cache_id.

Example

```
<?php
$smarty = new Smarty;

//setup directories here...

$smarty->setCaching(Smarty::CACHING_LIFETIME_CURRENT);
$smarty->setCacheLifetime(-1);

$userid = $_GET['userid'];
$smarty->cache_id = (string)$userid;

if(!$smarty->isCached('profile.tpl'))
    $smarty->assign('userData','some data');

$smarty->display('profile.tpl');
?>
```